# How to check that a method has called another method with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking, rspec-mocks

I have the following code structure (abbreviated for length):

```
module Uploader
  def self.execute(folder)
    report_record = Reporting::GenerateReports.call
    establish_api_connection
    upload_file(report_record.first_report, folder)
  end

  def self.upload_file(report, folder)
    upload_content(report.download, "/#{folder}/#{report.filename}")
  end

  def self.upload_content(content, path)
    ...
  end
end
```

At the moment, I can spec calling the `execute` method in RSpec to ensure that `upload_file` gets called.  However, how do I mock to check that `upload_file` calls `upload_content`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that `expect` and `allow` both *stub* the method call - they prevent it from actually running. If you want to check that one method was called, and also make sure *that* method calls another method, you need to use [`.and_call_original`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/message-expectations/calling-the-original-method).

```
# Some setup
folder = "some fake folder" # not sure the data type
report = Reporting::GenerateReports.call
allow(Reporting::GenerateReports).to receive(:call).and_return(stub_report)

# Expectations
expect(Uploader).to receive(:execute).with(some_folder).and_call_original
expect(Uploader).to receive(:upload_file).with(report, folder)
```

That `allow(Reporting::GenerateReports)` line is needed because the `report_record` variable is defined *inside* your `execute` method (cannot pass in a custom value from the tests via dependency injection). To ensure that the correct argument is passed to `upload_file`, it therefore needs to be stubbed out.

Comment: One nice trick is that `allow` creates a partial double so you can also use `have_received` to set expectations after the method has been called.  https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/spies#spy-on-a-method-on-a-partial-double

Comment: Thanks for this.  I have managed to test `upload_file` but it is `upload_content` which is called from `upload_file` that I need to check gets called.  Does your solution allow for that?  I assumed that I could test `upload_file` because it is called directly from `execute`.  But I was having problems with expecting messages to be received by `upload_content`.

Comment: So it's just the same thing. You can use `and_call_original`